# Alert shows value: Undefined

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I am beginner to Sencha Touch. I am using Sencha Architect.

I am working on a simple Navigation View Controller. For this I am refering sencha docs.

http://docs.sencha.com/architect/2/#!/guide/navigationview

But in the end it(Alert) is showing ::-

Your result is : Undefined.

But I already defined it as :

var result;

```
var mainNav = button.up('navigationview'),
    num1 = mainNav.child('step1').getValues().number1,
    num2 = mainNav.child('step2').getValues().number2,
    operation = mainNav.child('step3').getValues().operation;
var result;

switch (operation) {
    case 'add':
    result = num1 + num2;
    break;
    case 'subtract':
    result = num1 - num2;
    break;
    case 'multiply':
    result = num1 * num2;
    break;
    case 'divide':
    result = num1 / num2;
    break;
}

Ext.Msg.alert('Your result is: ' + result);
```

What to do?? I think this is very basic.

Thnx

Comment: Some code to go with it? Try [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: You should debug it. What are all the values? What branch does your code go through?

Answer (score 0):

Either num1 and num2 are undefined or none of the switch case executes.Try

```
  console.log(num1),console.log(num2) and console.log(operation)
```

before executing Switch statement. Similarly also see which of the case is executed and try consoling the result too like

```
case 'add':
    result = num1 + num2;
    console.log(result);
    break;
```

Comment: If `num1` or `num2` are `undefined`, then `result` is `NaN`. If one of them or both is `null`, it results in a number or `NaN`. Since the OP says that `result` is undefined, that means that no cases is executed. Anyway your answer is obviously the way to go, although I would recommend putting a breakpoint on the `switch` and inspecting everything...